# Checkout Bricks

Tags: api, mercadopago, checkout

como están? Un subscriptor en mi canal de YouTube me pidió que haga un video sobre Checkout Bricks. Investigue de que se trataba, y en la pagina de Mercado Pago Developers se encuentran los códigos a utilizar dependiendo de que Brick escojas. En mi caso, y para aprender como usar los bricks, decidi empezar con Payment Brick (hay cinco bricks a usar).

La pagina da codigo de Front end por un lado, y del back end (en mi caso, elegi php). Quiero aprender a usarlos, me seria de gran ayuda si alguien me puede guiar de como empezar.

Por lo pronto, tengo el codigo del front y del back. El front anda bien, sin embargo, no se que hay que modificar el back para que funcione. Apreto mi opcion para pagar, pongo confirmar y no hace nada, se queda en la misma pagina como si fuera un boton sin funcionalidad alguna que deberia hacer?

```
Front
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2">
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="paymentBrick_container">
      </div>
      <script>
      const mp = new MercadoPago('YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY', {
        locale: 'es'
      });
      const bricksBuilder = mp.bricks();
        const renderPaymentBrick = async (bricksBuilder) => {
          const settings = {
            initialization: {
          /*
            "amount" es el monto total a pagar por todos los medios de pago con excepción de la Cuenta de Mercado Pago y Cuotas sin tarjeta de crédito, las cuales tienen su valor de procesamiento determinado en el backend a través del "preferenceId"
          */
          amount: 10000,
          preferenceId: "<PREFERENCE_ID>",
          payer: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
          },
        },
        customization: {
          visual: {
            style: {
              theme: "default",
            },
          },
          paymentMethods: {
            creditCard: "all",
                                        debitCard: "all",
                                        ticket: "all",
                                        bankTransfer: "all",
                                        atm: "all",
                                        onboarding_credits: "all",
                                        wallet_purchase: "all",
            maxInstallments: 1
          },
        },
        callbacks: {
          onReady: () => {
            /*
             Callback llamado cuando el Brick está listo.
             Aquí puede ocultar cargamentos de su sitio, por ejemplo.
            */
          },
          onSubmit: ({ selectedPaymentMethod, formData }) => {
            // callback llamado al hacer clic en el botón de envío de datos
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              fetch("/process_payment", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
              })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => {
                  // recibir el resultado del pago
                  resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // manejar la respuesta de error al intentar crear el pago
                  reject();
                });
            });
          },
          onError: (error) => {
            // callback llamado para todos los casos de error de Brick
            console.error(error);
          },
        },
      };
      window.paymentBrickController = await bricksBuilder.create(
        "payment",
        "paymentBrick_container",
        settings
      );
    };
    renderPaymentBrick(bricksBuilder);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
  
back-end:

Crédito/Débito

    <?php
      require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
      use MercadoPagoMercadoPagoConfig;
      MercadoPagoConfig::setAccessToken("PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN");

      $contents = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
      
      $createRequest = [
        "transaction_amount" => 100,
        "description" => "description",
        "payment_method_id" => "pix",
          "payer" => [
            "email" => $contents['payer']['email'],
            "identification" => [
              "type" => $contents['payer']['identification']['type'],
              "number" => $contents['payer']['identification']['number']
            ]
          ],
          "payment" => [
            "transaction_amount" => $contents['transaction_amount'],
            "token" => $contents['token'],
            "installments" => $contents['installments'],
            "payment_method_id" => $contents['payment_method_id'],
            "issuer_id" => $contents['issuer_id']
          ]
      ];

      $client = new PaymentClient();
      $request_options = new MPRequestOptions();
      $request_options->setCustomHeaders(["X-Idempotency-Key: <SOME_UNIQUE_VALUE>"]);
    
      $client->create($createRequest, $request_options);
    ?>
    
Transferência Bancária

      <?php
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

        MercadoPagoSDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");

        $payment = new MercadoPagoPayment();
        $payment->transaction_amount = 100;
        $payment->description = "Título do produto";
        $payment->payment_method_id = "pix";
        $payment->payer = array(
            "email" => "test@test.com",
            "first_name" => "Test",
            "last_name" => "User",
            "identification" => array(
                "type" => "CPF",
                "number" => "19119119100"
            ),
            "address"=>  array(
                "zip_code" => "06233200",
                "street_name" => "Av. das Nações Unidas",
                "street_number" => "3003",
                "neighborhood" => "Bonfim",
                "city" => "Osasco",
                "federal_unit" => "SP"
            )
          );

        $payment->save();

      ?>
    
Ticket

      <?php
      require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

      MercadoPagoSDK::setAccessToken("ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN");

      $payment = new MercadoPagoPayment();
      $payment->transaction_amount = 100;
      $payment->description = "Título do produto";
      $payment->payment_method_id = "bolbradesco";
      $payment->payer = array(
          "email" => "test@test.com",
          "first_name" => "Test",
          "last_name" => "User",
          "identification" => array(
              "type" => "CPF",
              "number" => "19119119100"
           ),
          "address"=>  array(
              "zip_code" => "06233200",
              "street_name" => "Av. das Nações Unidas",
              "street_number" => "3003",
              "neighborhood" => "Bonfim",
              "city" => "Osasco",
              "federal_unit" => "SP"
           )
        );

      $payment->save();

     ?>
```

Comment: no hace nada.. no envia? envia y no llega nada? envia, llega y no funciona? en todo caso, debes especificar mas donde esta el problema...